# When run rbx1_nav, and rviz :fixed frame :fixed frame [map] do not exist

Tags: rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,everyone. I install ros-by-exanple-indigo code on my computer.And I prepare to test fake robot simulator.However,Once I run the .launch file there will be a mistake in rviz.See follow.

run command:

```
roscore
```

and

```
roslaunch rbx1_bringup fake_turtlebot.launch
```

Then:

```
rosrun rviz rviz -d 'rospack find rbx1_nav' /sim.rviz
```

then there's a mistake in rviz,

```
Global Status ：error fixed frame :fixed frame [map] do not exist
```

(the node works fine, as I publish the command to it and it can show it moves from the command line screen. So there should be some problems with the rviz I guess.)

What direction should I go?

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/250081/when-run-rbx1_nav,-and-rviz-:fixed-frame-:fixed-frame-%5Bmap%5D-do-not-exist/) by [jimmyjiao](https://answers.ros.org/users/27100/jimmyjiao/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2016-12-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Self-answering again...:
Found this tool is quite useful: roswtf. It tells me that my ROS_HOSTNAME is not set correctly. I just changed my IP and my hostname to this machine, so that's the reason.

Suggestion would be:

change your IP address in /etc/hosts and /etc/network/interfaces. And make sure in the ~/.bashrc your IP address is correct. For a single machine, suggest your IP address is set to 127.0.0.1.

---

Originally posted by [jimmyjiao](https://answers.ros.org/users/27100/jimmyjiao/) with karma: 41 on 2016-12-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0